# Cant run azure site in my development computer

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to code a website for azure. First I'm trying to run a simple test... but I'm not being able to run the simplest test ever... a cloud service with 1 web role (asp.net mvc4 site) with only 1 action (homepage).

I'm using Visual studio 2012 (Ultimate) and I just installed Azure SDK (version 2.1). When I run the website, the emulator starts and everything seems fine. But when the page opens in my Firefox it says "The connection was reset" and the page doesn't load.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... I'm trying like a "hello world" for azure... it should work pretty straight forward. I tried using other ports for the endpoint (8081, 9595, etc) but the result was the same. I also disabled windows firewall... just in case.

I would really appreciate any help... I've been stuck with this for several hours and I really don't know what else to try.

Comment: I found something... if in the azure project properties I select to use the "Emulator Express" it starts and I the homepage loads. So it seems to be with the "Full Emulator". 

It doesnt make sense because Im starting the Visual Studio as Administrator and the Compute and Storage emulator are started when I hit F5. Any ideas why the "Full Emulator" might be not working? Thanks!

Comment: Trippel check that you are running elevated, Since the major difference between Full emulator and Express is that express can be used without elevated privileges.

Comment: Yep, I triple checked and Im running as Administrator. It asks me for permission when opening the Visual Studio and it says "(Administrator)" at the top of the window. Unfortunately that doesnt seem to be the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on, as a simple F5 on a brand new MVC4 project should "just work." Having said that:

- Make sure you're running VS2012 as administrator, otherwise it won't launch the emulator.
- Make sure your Azure project is the startup project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added a comment to my question which is related to your suggestions. It seems to be an issue with the "Full Emulator", but Im running visual studio as administrator...